# Unable to extract value from json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I am a Rails newbie who's attempting to extract a value from json. The code for the view goes like this:

```
<% companyarray = @companies.select do |hash| 
                    hash.id == acquisition.acquirer_id
                  end %>
<%= JSON.parse(companyarray.to_json)[0]["name"] %>
```

Before I use to_json on companyarray, the dataset I would get is like this:

```
[#<Company id: 504, name: "test", website: "http://info.test.com/", created_at: "2013-08-09 13:27:16", updated_at: "2013-08-09 13:27:16", base_id: nil>]
```

All said and done, I am unable to extract the key value from the array of hashes. I ended up getting a `undefined method []' for nil:NilClass` error.

This is what my Rails controller looks like:

```
class AcquisitionsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @acquisitions = Acquisition.all
    @companies = Company.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
          format.json
    end
  end
end
```

I'm not sure what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can skip converting to json, and just use the companies directly:

```
<% companyarray = @companies.select do |hash| 
                hash.id == acquisition.acquirer_id
              end %>
<%= companyarray[0].name %>
```

Comment: Hmm I tried that and got a `undefined method name' for nil:NilClass` error.

Comment: @batmanbegins then you're not getting any companies back and have an empty array.